# How to remove an event in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On my Vue instance I have this:

```
async mounted () {
  document.addEventListener('paste', this.onPasteEvent)
},
beforeDestroy () {
  document.removeEventListener('paste', this.onPasteEvent)
},
methods: {
  onPasteEvent () {
    return async (event) => {
      try {
        const items = event.clipboardData.items
        const files = await this.getBase64Files(items)

        this.transferedItems = files
        this.modal = true
      } catch (error) {
        this.$toast.error('Não foi possível detectar um arquivo na área de transferência.')
      }
    }
  },
```

I'm trying to destroy the "paste" event when the component is destroyed, but this just doesnt work, I know I need to pass the same reference to `removeEventListener`, but is this not the same reference?

The only way I found to make this work is placing the `onPasteEvent` method outside the Vue instance as a `constant`, but that way I don't have access to `this` instance, which is important to me, also, I can't pass anything as arguments, if I try to pass something, looks like my function create a new reference on memory, making unable to destroy it using `removeEventListener`.

Please, I just don't understand how to remove a event in JavaScript, can someone help me with that example? I already saw a lot of similar questions but no one explains:

- How to keep the method reference even if it has parameters?
- How to remove the event working with Vue instances?

Comment: I don't know if it helps but you could check a flag inside the onPasteEvent handler that just returns if true and set it when you need instead of having to remove the event listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is already removing the event listener correctly, but there's a couple other problems:

`onPasteEvent` returns a function, so when the `paste` event occurs, the handler only returns a new function (which does not get executed), so it's basically doing nothing useful.

To fix the `paste` event handler, convert the returned function into the `onPasteEvent` function itself:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    async onPasteEvent (event) {
      try {
        const items = event.clipboardData.items
        const files = await this.getBase64Files(items)

        this.transferedItems = files
        this.modal = true
      } catch (error) {
        this.$toast.error('Não foi possível detectar um arquivo na área de transferência.')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And if you're using Vue 3, the `beforeDestroy` hook from Vue 2 is [renamed to `beforeUnmount`](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/introduction.html#other-minor-changes):

```js
export default {
  // beforeDestroy() { ❌ renamed in Vue 3

  beforeUnmount() { ✅
    document.removeEventListener('paste', this.onPasteEvent)
  },
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-remove-paste-event-listener?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FPasteWatcher.vue)

Comment: The event is automatically passed to the event handler. Passing additional args is beyond the scope of the original question. I recommend posting a new question about that so that someone familiar with the topic could answer. I'll chime in if I can.